# Unity Raycasthit doesn't recognized object with tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object in my game that is tagged as "Enemy" and it's in a layer called "Enemy" as well. It has a `BoxCollider` and a `Rigidbody` attached to it. The option `IsTrigger` is activated. When I shoot at it the hit is not recognized. The hit passes right through it.

I use this method to shoot:

```
void DisparaBala()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(maiCam.transform.position, maiCam.transform.forward, out hit))
    {
        print("We hit: " + hit.transform.gameObject.tag);
        if (hit.transform.tag == Tags.ENEMY_TAG)
        {
            hit.transform.GetComponent<ScriptVida>().DanoAplicado(damage);
        }
    }
}
```

The gun is child of a camera which is child of the player. The player is in a layer called "Player".

The funny thing is if I put any other object with the tag "Enemy" the hit is recognized normally.

I don't know what to do.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwQMX.jpg)

Comment: Well, what is different about the object you tag enemy and works and the one that doesnt? there has to be one.

Comment: Raycast needs to hit a collider, does your object have one ?

Comment: @Jichael on the pic the currently selected object has one, but enemy is written against the object below - its kinda hard to tell

Comment: Yes man, it has box collider attached to it. The one that works is in default layer, but I tried to put the enemy in this layer as well and it didn't work

Comment: The one called "Indio" is the enemy man. It's the same prefab displayed in the screen.

Comment: As I said, what are the differences between the one you tag as enemy and it works and the one that does not?

Comment: The one that works is just a cube, and the one that doesn't is the enemy prefab which is a zombie.

Answer (score 0):

Add a layer mask to your Physics.Raycast.  Like so:

```
void DisparaBala()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    int layerMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Enemy");
    if(Physics.Raycast(maiCam.transform.position, maiCam.transform.forward, out hit, layerMask))
    {
        print("We hit: " + hit.transform.gameObject.tag);
        if (hit.transform.tag == Tags.ENEMY_TAG)
        {
            hit.transform.GetComponent<ScriptVida>().DanoAplicado(damage);
        }
    }
}
```